# Convert data from var type to Version type

Tags: c#, var

How to convert data from var type to Version type in c#? I am using .net framework 3.5 SP1.

Comment: There is no `var` type.  Please show us your code.

Comment: `var` is just a compiler thing, there's no such type.

Comment: var comes under System.String
Refer this site http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/09/28/GettingNativeFileInfoInTheCompactFramework.aspx
Check line no 17,18,30,32....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` in C# is not a type but a keyword. It means the type of the variable is inferred from whatever is assigned to it.

for example:

```
 var x = new Whatever();
```

is exactly the same as

```
 Whatever x = new Whatever();
```

read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: Nit: it's a contextual keyword. You can still use it as an identifier. Heck, if you've got a type called `var` you could write `var var = new var();`. I suggest you don't though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet you're evil. Go away! :-)